# Laravel - calling model's method throws undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got a problem with model's method with parameters. I've got 2 `Page` and `ContentTranslation`. I want to get `ContentTranslation` based on language, so I've got following method in `Page` model:

```
public function contentTranslations($language) {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ContentTranslation')->where('language', $language);
}
```

and then I've got a method in `PageController` for getting the pages based on language:

```
public function getPagesByLanguage($language)
{
    $pages = Page::orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page->contentTranslations($language);
    }
    $return $pages;
}
```

I'm returning my results in JSON format (I'm using Laravel as an api). But this approach doesn't work. It throws me error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::contentTranslations()

Some time ago, I wanted to return `contentTranslations` for all languages, so I haven't got a parameter in `contentTranslations` model method and everything worked fine after calling `$page->contentTranslations;` in foreach loop. Why I've got the trouble with passing parameter into method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [eager loading to avoid N+1 query problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function getPagesByLanguage($language)
{
    return Page::with(['contentTranslations' => function($q) use ($language) {
                    $q->where('language', $language);
               }])
               ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
               ->get();
}
```

Also change your relation to:

```
public function contentTranslations() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ContentTranslation');
}
```

Comment: Great, it works as I expected ... but what if I want to now select only some columns from `contentTranslations`? I tried to add `->select(array('slug', 'language')` after `$q->where...` statement, but then it return 0 items in content_translations array. Could you also help me with this? :)

Comment: You can do this `$q->where('language', $language)->select(['page_id', 'slug', 'language'];` Note that you always have to add foreign key to make relation work.